# How to verify SSH is connected via dropbear?

Tags: dropbear

An Asus RT68U is remotely accessible via SSH.  Once logged in from the command line (Ubuntu 16.04), what command can be issued to verify that the shell is connected via dropbear or something else?

I suspect that the connection is dropbear, but would like strong confirmation from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the advertised version of the remote server, use `ssh -v` (verbose).  Here an example of connecting *from* a machine with OpenSSH *to* a machine with dropbear:

```
user@machine:~ $ ssh -v ${ip-address}
...
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_2013.60
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`ps axjf | less +/axjf` And follow the tree down to the sshd command.

If it has a generic name, like mine, then `/usr/sbin/sshd --version` or `strings /usr/sbin/sshd | less`